# How to create a Mongoose schema that saves input as html in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a blog website with an admin panel in which a user can write the body of the blog's content in the text editor tinyMCE. Currently my schema for blog body is set to string but everytime I write a blog you can see the html marks around the blog and the markup is not recognized as html. Is this an issue with the schema being set to string?

Comment: It has nothing to do with schemas/db.

Comment: Ok so any clue what I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: How are you including the body content in the web page? Are you using some kind of templating engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use it in my projects in a similar way. I save tinyMCE content to mongo as a string and thus is saved with the html tags. If you want display these contents out of tinyMCE editor you have to make the template language output  the unescaped value into the template. Lets say that your data are stored as `description`. If you use ejs you can display it without html tags using this `<%- description %>`.

Comment: I cannot believe I did not think of that! I'm actually trying to render it as html and it is showing as plain text, so I should just use ejs to render it as html correct?

Comment: Right, use the this <%- tag like the example i gave you. Wait to hear from you that worked.

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I cannot believe I've been working on this for 3 days and it was as simple as having the ejs tag wrong!