# Display HTML from Form on a page as HTML instead of HTML Code

Tags: html, express, mongoose, tinymce, ejs

I'm creating a node app with mongodb. 
I'm using TinyMCE in textareas for input. When I save it to the database and want to show it somewhere on a page, I see the HTML Code `(<p>This is a paragraph</p>)` instead of the actual rendered HTML.
When I console.log() the item from the ejs file I get this:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>I was here:</p>
<p>Link</p>
```

But when I look into the source code of the page I see this:

```
&lt;p&gt;I was here:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Link&lt;/p&gt;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188389/how-to-create-a-mongoose-schema-that-saves-input-as-html-in-mongodb

Comment: You should unscape html. Here is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/2260920

Comment: Ah I completly forgot about <%- %> in ejs. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution:

In ejs there is the <%- for unescaped values, which I forgot. 
https://ejs.co/#docs